# Write to txt file

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem when trying to write to a txt file. I'm making a car register and after adding 2 cars to it, it looks like this in the txt file.

```
BMW
 Car
 ABCD1234
 Herald
 45
Fiat
 Car
 QWER1234
 RONALD
 20
```

My wish is to get it on the same line like this.

```
BMW Car ABCD1234 Herald 45
Fiat Car QWER1234 RONALD 20
```

This is my "save" and "add vehicle" function atm.

```
int save(vehicle_t * v, int count)
{
    FILE * f;
    f = fopen("reg.txt", "w");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
            fprintf(f, "%s %s %s %s %d\n", v[i].brand, v[i].type, v[i].reg, v[i].owner.name, v[i].owner.age);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

```
void add_vehicle(vehicle_t *v, int count)
{
    char brand[NSIZE]; char type[NSIZE]; char reg[NSIZE]; char name[NSIZE];
    int age;
    printf("Brand: ");
    fgets(brand, NSIZE, stdin);
    strcpy(v[count].brand, brand);
    
    printf("Type of vehicle: ");
    fgets(type, NSIZE, stdin);
    strcpy(v[count].type, type);
    
    printf("Reg number: ");
    fgets(reg, NSIZE, stdin);
    strcpy(v[count].reg, reg);

    printf("Owners name: ");
    fgets(name, NSIZE, stdin);
    strcpy(v[count].owner.name, name);

    printf("Owners age: ");
    v[count].owner.age = num_check(MAX_AGE, MIN_AGE);
}
```

My thought is that `fgets` adds `\n` at the end of an array, but how do I get rid of this problem when working with structs?

Comment: *"fgets adds \n at the end of an array"* - nope, but close, it *keeps* the terminating newline that caused it to stop reading in the first place. [See `fgets` here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). If you want it gone you have to hunt it down and set the terminator yourself. And fyi, structs have *nothing* to do with this. The same scenario would transpire with a simple text read using `fgets` into a simple one-shot line buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me it just seems harder to fix when structs are involved, but it looks like I can fix it pretty much the same way as in a "one line text".

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` returns all the characters on the line **including the trailing `\n`**. To keep `fprintf` from printing the `\n` characters you can change the `fprintf` call to

```
fprintf(f, "%*.*s %*.*s %*.*s %*.*s %d\n",
          strlen(v[i].brand)-1,      strlen(v[i].brand)-1,      v[i].brand,
          strlen(v[i].type)-1,       strlen(v[i].type)-1,       v[i].type,
          strlen(v[i].reg)-1,        strlen(v[i].reg)-1,        v[i].reg,
          strlen(v[i].owner.name)-1, strlen(v[i].owner.name)-1, v[i].owner.name,
          v[i].owner.age);
```

This instructs it to output all but the last character of each string.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the terminator one position to the left with:

```
fgets(name, NSIZE, stdin);
name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';
```

or you could use scanf:

```
scanf("%100[^\n]%*c", name);
//but here I've put a maximum 100 chars inside the string, 
//not using the variable
```

There are other ways to do that with scanf but if you are a beginner I'd recommend you to stick with one of the two options above.

Comment: Be **very** careful when doing the former. If (a) the unchecked `fgets` call fails, and (b) the target buffer is already terminated at location-0, the result will most assuredly *not* be what you want, namely `name[SIZE_MAX] = '\0';`